# Multiple User Types in Laravel 4 - Login Issues

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, laravel, laravel-4

I am doing a project for school and I need more than one user type : User, Registrar and Teacher.

I followed Laravel documentation and got the user working perfectly (login/register).

Then I tried adding another user: Registrar. I got the registration working and it's even adding the user in the "registrar" table.

But when I'm trying to log in it is using the "users" table, not the "registrar" one, and giving me a controller method "not found" error.

Model: Registrar.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class Registrar extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
    protected $table = 'registrar';
    protected $hidden = array('password');
    public function getAuthIdentifier() {
        return $this->getKey();
    }
    public function getAuthPassword() {
        return $this->password;
    }
}
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('/', array('uses' => 'HomeController@AuthenticateUser'));

Route::get('/student/member', array('uses' => 'UsersController@getStudent'));

Route::get('logout', array('uses' => 'UsersController@doLogout'));

Route::controller('users', 'UsersController');

Route::controller('password', 'RemindersController');

Route::controller('registrar', 'RegistrarController');

Route::get('/registrar/member', array('uses' => 'RegistrarController@getRegistrar'));
```

RegistrarController, Sign-In method:

```
public function postSignin() {
    if (Auth::attempt(array('email'=>Input::get('login_input')) {
        return Redirect::to('registrar/member')->with('status', 'You are now logged in!');
    } else {
        return Redirect::to('registrar/login')
            ->with('error', 'Your username/password combination was incorrect')
            ->withInput();
    }
}
```

Other functions inside:

```
class RegistrarController extends BaseController {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->beforeFilter('csrf', array('on'=>'post'));
        $this->beforeFilter('auth', array('only'=>array('getRegistrar')));
    }
    public function getRegister() {
        return View::make('registrar.register');
    }
    public function getRegistrar() {
        return View::make('registrar.member');
    }
```

login.blade.php

```
{{ Form::open(array('url'=>'registrar/signin', 'class'=>'form-signin' , 'id'=>'login-form')) }}
.
.
.
.
-- form close--
```

I'm wondering if this line is not the problem in the signin function:

```
if (Auth::attempt(array('email'=>Input::get('login_input')) {
        return Redirect::to('registrar/member')->with('status', 'You are now logged in!')
```

As I'm not sure how the system checks which database table to use, or its default on the "users".

Comment: I think it is better to use roles here instead of seprate databases for members. Entrust for example on github is a package that supports roles for members. That way you have only one user datatable that can have many roles. One of these roles could be registrar or teacher or whatever. https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust

Comment: It is actually a small project and we need to use basic mysql operations etc... like 1 table for users , 1 for registrar etc....

Comment: There is either a problem with the postSignin method ( one of the functions inside is hardcoded to use the "users" table ) , or the controller is not linking to it properly.

Comment: Check out Antonio's answer below.  When a user signs in though, you would have to dynamically modify that setting depending on what type they are.  Something like `Config::set('auth.model', $userType);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this to swap the model during runtime:

```
$provider = new \Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider(app('hash'), 'Registrar');

Auth::setProvider($provider);
```

Comment: Hi , If i replace the User , then the first user type will not work . Is there any way to add both ?

Comment: - Thanks - the login works but I'm still having the controller method not found tho on : http://localhost:8000/registrar/member . The error message is not well defined , is there any way to know which one of my files/line is causing the error ? Error pic : http://2.ii.gl/6Z6Mc4.png   . It doesnt even say which method is causing the error

Comment: Try to invert the order of your routes, it's a routing problem. Your '/registrar/member' might be being resolved in the Route::controller() and it shouldn't.

Comment: here are all my routes :

Comment: Route::get('/', array('uses' => 'HomeController@AuthenticateUser'));

Route::get('/student/member', array('uses' => 'UsersController@getStudent'));

Route::get('logout', array('uses' => 'UsersController@doLogout'));




Route::controller('users', 'UsersController');

Route::controller('password', 'RemindersController');

Route::controller('student', 'StudentController');


Route::controller('registrar', 'RegistrarController');

Route::get('/registrar/member', array('uses' => 'RegistrarController@getRegistrar'));

Comment: I Also added all the routes in the main post